# Can't using constructor c++

Tags: c++, pointers, object, vector, constructor

I Have constructor for the class Game, which define a Deck.
**Game.cpp:**

```
Game::Game(char*configurationFile):turn(0), playingPlayer(0)
{
    vector<Card*> vec;
    deck(vec);
    initialState ="";
}
```

**Game.h:**

```
private:
    Deck deck;
```

and the **constructor of Deck:**

```
Deck::Deck(vector <Card*> vec):deck(vec), NumOfCard(vec.size()){}
```

of course its only some parts of the code, but I keep getting the **error**:

> no match for call to ‘(Deck) (std::vector&)’

on line : `deck(vec);`
and I cant understand why. Thanks all for helping!

Comment: Well, `deck(vec)` is not a constructor call.  Not even inside the constructor of an object having `deck` as a subobject.  That's what the ctor-initializer-list (which you already have) is for.

Comment: right, you should have `deck =vec;` instead of `deck(vec);` if that is what you want

Comment: @BenVoigt so plaese help m. I dont understand, what should I write?

Comment: Afraid it's time to open up the text book and start reading, Kiprin. You appear to have inherited code that you do not understand, nor do you understand the correct solutions presented. That shows an information gap that should be plugged before someone provides you with more code you don't understand.

Comment: @marcinj thanks it helped ! but can you explain to me please what happened there? im not really understanding how it works all the pointers and references thing

Comment: @Kiprin if you wanted to initialize `deck` with `vec`, then correct syntax in your source code is `deck = vec;` not `deck(vec);`. My first comment was wrong, I will remove it.

Comment: What has `vector<Player *> players` got to do with this?

Comment: @marcinj: That's still wrong. You must write `deck(vec)` in the constructor's member-initialisation list if you want to initialise `deck`. Otherwise all you're doing is assigning after-the-fact.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit - you are right, for some reasons I thought deck was of type `vector<Card*>`

Comment: BTW, the `vec` is a **local** variable in your constructor and *will disappear after execution leaves the constructor*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets make some order here. In the Game.h file you'd want to declare all you class members and class functions (in some cases, you can even provide implementation to your functions in the header, or write them as inline, but that's not the case)
So **Game.h**:

```
private:
   vector<Player *> players;  //The list of the players
   Deck deck;
   string initialState; int turn; int playingPlayer;
```

Notice that you don't need to create local object, since you probably dont need that vector after the constructor finishes. Also, if you have a subobject as a class member, unless you initialize it in the init-list, it will be constructed with the default constructor, hence the call in your original code invokes the copy assignment operator.
You can see this in this simple code:

http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/87521f4578736d78

You can indeed implement the constructor in the CPP file, hence **Game.cpp**:

```
Game::Game(char *configurationFile):turn(0), playingPlayer(0),initiateState(""), deck(vector<Card *>()){}
```

Now, for the construction of deck you'd probably want:

```
Deck::Deck(const vector<Card *>&vec){ //implement according to your class}
```

Notice that in your code, you made a really weird call in `deck(vec)`, perhaps you meant Deck(vec), which also doesn't make sense since it a recursive call to the constructor itself.

Hope that helped a bit.